# Karate framework default path

Tags: karate

In my test all requests use the same url ('http://localhost:8080/example')

I defined that url in background section:

```
Feature: Some feature
   Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:8080/example'
```

Is there a better way to write this?

```
Scenario:
Given path ''
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Given path ''`. You can start with the `* request {}`.